# Create a void method for each button

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi im hoping someone can assist im still new to programming and this is a noob question but i have created a Visual studio - C# (Windows Form Application) and now the question reads to Create a void method for each of my buttons i created in the form and telling me even what to name the method.

but on my research The void keyword is used in method signatures to declare a method that does not return a value.

LinkToAddresses () will be my void method for address the (button), so my question is do i just put in this void method and its going to do nothing?

im just going to link the full question maybe im just really not understanding this>?

''
The below form will represent the main form from which the user will navigate to the other forms. Meaning each button should be linked to the appropriate form. E.g. If button Manage Addresses is clicked the form managed addresses should be displayed. The Exit button should successfully terminate the program.

Create a void method for each button and name them as follow: LinkToAddresses (), LinkToCustomers (), LinkToDrivers (), LinkToStatus (), and LinkToFreight (). The methods should be called under the appropriate button. For the exit button create a void method named AppExit () this should terminate the program.
''

I would appreciate any help or guidance, thank you in advance.

Comment: [Void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/void) doesn't mean it is going to do nothing, it will just not return an object. The method can still complete an action without returning an object. It would be helpful to post what you have tried so far so people can help you. If you are following a tutorial, please post the link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual studio usually handles the button actions easily. Just place the buttons on your form, then rename the buttons to LinkToAddresses, LinkToCustomers, LinkToDrivers, LinkToStatus, LinkToFreight and AppExit. Then simply just double click on the each button and visual studio will create a void method for their click event.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YourApp
{
    public partial class FormMain : Form
    {

        private FormManagedAddresses formManagedAddresses = null;

        public FormMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LinkToAddresses_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (formManagedAddresses != null)
            {
                formManagedAddresses.Close();
            }
            formManagedAddresses = new FormNews();
            formManagedAddresses.Show();
        }

        private void AppExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to a buttons function, is the Click Event Handler. While specific names vary based on Display technology (WinForms, WPF/UWP, ASP.Net), that is  the general pattern for Graphical User Interfaces. It is called [event driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Even things that have a different programm flow like Games and Web Applications usually try to imitate it.

The signature of a event is given during its definition and must be *strictly* followed. Usually `void NameOfTheEvent(object sender, SampleEventArgs e)`.
A return type of void is extremely common with events. If there is to be any output, that usually is handeled via a property in the Event Args or by directly doing stuff with the other GUI Elements.

If you want a button to do nothing, you just *never give it a event handler*. Every single button you ever used, was given a implicit or explicit event handler to do exactly what it did. If you want it to conditionally do nothing, either disable the Button so it can not be clicked, or put a proper if-statement into the event Handler.

A advanced topic would be the command pattern, where there is a bunch of commands in code behind. And each button, menu item and key combination is meerely a way to trigger said command - a representation for hte user to call the command.

You can share a single event across any number of Elements. AS you can see above, the pattern for events includes `object sender` as argument. This means you can check if it is a specific Button instance that called the event. Or even "unpack" the specific button, do look at stuff like Display String, Tag to get data from it. However, as a general rule retrieving data from the GUI is a bit frowned - ideally the GUI should only represent the data in the backend.